# Does it make sense to test assertArrayHasKey and later test value using assertEquals?

Tags: php, unit-testing, automated-tests

Does it make sense to test assertArrayHasKey and later test it's value using assertEquals, or when I'm expecting specific value, I should ommit testing testArrayHasKey - I will get "Undefined index: id" in the next assertion anyway.

I'm aware that difference is in feedback (F vs. E) but does it make any difference in real life?

Answer (score 0):

An error will show you that something in your test didn't met *your* expectations, you as the person writing the test.

For the expectation of the test, it will fail in case of error as well. So you will get a "fail" in both ways.

So it depends what you expect. If in normal operation the array will have the key and you're interested in testing for a specific value, assert the value and you're done. **Keep tests simple.**

If it's more common that you get an error in there then, your test might not be actually fitting your needs so getting an error will then signal you that you might want to refactor your test(s).

Comment: I want to test this value, if it's formatted as I'm expecting it to be. Should I test for it's key existance first? Or just - as you wrote it - keep it simple, and skip assertArrayHasKey test?

Comment: If you skip the key assert, then your test will not only fail if the value doesn't equal but it will even give an error on top. I would prefer that in theory so I know about problems more drastically.